# Problems to fit a table into a column of a twocolumn environment

Tags: tables, multicol

I'm trying to fit a table into one column of a twocolumn environment but everytime I try to fit it in just one column, it disappears. What should I do ?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx, array}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
 \usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
 \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nottoc, notlof, notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.20cm, bottom=2.20cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\lipsum

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum

\begin{table}[htb]
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| }
 \hline \textbf{inf.} & \textbf{part. pass. it.} & \textbf{part. pass. lat.} & \textbf{derivé} \\  
 \hline bere & bevuto & bibitus & bevizione \\  
 \hline cedere & ceduto & cessus & cessione \\   
 \hline convenire & convenuto & conventus & convenzione \\   
 \hline intervenire  & intervenuto & interventus & intervenzione \\   
  \hline possedere & posseduto & possessus & possessione \\   
 \hline perdere & perduto & perditus & perdizione \\   
 \hline precedere & preceduto & praecessus & precessione \\    
 \hline procedere & proceduto & processus & processione \\  
 \hline premere & premuto & pressus & pressione \\   
 \hline ricevere & ricevuto & receptus & ricezione \\   
 \hline riflettere & riflettuto & reflexus & riflessione \\   
 \hline ripetere & ripetuto & repetitus & ripetizione \\  
 \hline ritenere & ripetuto & repetitus & ripetizione \\   
 \hline vendere & venduto & venditus & vendizione \\      
 \hline volere & voluto & -- & volizione \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: just remove the `table` environment as (a) it doesn't work and (b) you don't need it. Just use `tabular`

Answer (score 2):

read the documentation of the `multicol` package.  here is the relevant item
from the "warnings" section:

> `Floats and marginpars not allowed inside multicols environment!`
>
> This message appears if you try to use the `\marginpar` command or an
>   unstarred version of the `figure` or `table` environment. Such floats will
>   disappear!

**edit:**
as pointed out by david carlisle in a comment, it isn't necessary to wrap your
table in a float.  you can simply input the `tabular` structure in the location where you want the table to appear in the output.

Comment: So, what should I do to make this work ? Or do I have to leave it outside of the columns ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked best for me was to put it into a minipage :

```
    \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
        \begin{table}[H]
            \begin{flushleft}
        \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
            \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| }
            \hline \textbf{inf.} & \textbf{part. pass. it.} & \textbf{part. pass. lat.} & \textbf{derivé} \\  
            \hline bere & bevuto & bibitus & bevizione \\  
            \hline vendere & venduto & venditus & vendizione \\      
            \hline volere & voluto & -- & volizione \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}}
   \end{flushleft}
    \end{table} 
    \end{minipage}
```

Comment: Why you use a `figure` environment? I don't see any reasonable reason for that (even caption is not used!). And, even if you use `H` option for table, put float into mini-page is bad habit and can cause unexpected problems.